# Does a power series vanish on the circle of convergence imply that the power series equals to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ be a power series, $a_n, z\in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose the radius of convergence of $f$ is $1$, and $f$ is convergent at every point of the unit circle.

**Question**:If $f(z)=0$ for every $|z|=1$, then can we draw the conclusion that $a_n=0$ for all nonnegative integer $n$?

I think the answer is *yes*, but I failed to prove it. My approach is concerning about the function $F_\lambda(z):=f(\lambda z)$ for $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$, $|z|=1$. Abel's theorem shows that $F_\lambda$ converge to $F_1$ pointwisely as $\lambda\rightarrow 1$ on the unit circle. If I have the property that $f$ is bounded in the unit disk, then I can apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to prove $a_0=0$, and by induction I can prove $a_n=0$ for all $n$. However, I cannot prove $f(z) $ is bounded in the unit disk.

Any answers or comments are welcome. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe I'm making some very stupid mistake, but isn't $f$ continuous on the unit disk since it's the pointwise limit of uniformly continuous functions?

Comment: Can you use the Maximum modulus theorem?

Comment: A pointwise limit of uniformly continuous functions need not be continuous.

Comment: @jerrysciencemath : Are you satisfied with my answer below?

Comment: @MalikYounsi: I'm sorry that I'm busy doing other things these days, I haven't check the document in your reply, but it seems to be a satisfactory answer~ If I have time, I will check it through details, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @jerrysciencemath : No problem! You're welcome.

Comment: @MalikYounsi: Thanks for your answer! Your document is very clear~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a particular case of an old Theorem from Cantor (1870), called Cantor's uniqueness theorem. The theorem says that if, for every real $x$,
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{inx}=0,$$
then all the complex numbers $c_n$'s are zero.

You can google "Uniqueness of Representation by Trigonometric Series" for more information. See e.g. [this document](http://math.depaul.edu/mash/monthly_uniqueness.pdf) for a proof and some history of the result.

Comment: Yes, I think this correct: +1. By the way, you seem to know a lot about holomorphic functions: are they a field you specialize in ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : Thank you, I also think it is correct. This question really is more about trigonometric series than anything else : the fact that $f(x)$ converges on the unit circle implies that the radius of convergence is $\geq 1$, and if the radius is $>1$ then the result is trivial... So the hypothesis about the radius of convergence does not mean much. About holomorphic functions, I am a PhD student in complex analysis, so I've read a lot about this subject. I'm interested in other fields too though.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, Malik, and best wishes for your PhD.

Comment: I'm removing an answer I gave which was way off. Thanks to those who pointed that out...